# How to find if object of a class exists

Tags: c#, wpf, object, instanceof

On my ListBoxItem MouseEnter event I am creating a new window with the following code.

```
Window w = new Window();
w.Show();
```

When the mouse leaves the current item I want to close the window.

How do I do that?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store a reference to the window (`w` in your case) in a place where both the event handler for MouseEnter and MouseExit can access it and then just do a `w.Close()`.

Comment: Hi, I have been thinking on the same line, but how do I store a reference?

Comment: @Anand: Usually you do this with a field in the class.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the w in a local variable, store it in a member variable of the current class. On MouseExit, use the member variable to close the Window.

```
public partial class ListWindow
{
    Window displayWindow;

    public void OnListBoxItem_MouseEnter()
    {
        displayWindow = new Window();
        displayWindow.Show();
    }

    public void OnListBoxItem_MouseExit()
    {
        displayWindow.Close();
    }
}
```